# Can Gitlab expose build and coverage badges to anonymous users?

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api

We are hosting some repository on GitHub, some other on GitLab.

Sometimes, the package is published but not the source code.

We always display build status and code coverage in `README.md`.

Is there a way to have build and coverage badge on GitLab always accessible to anonymous?

Comment: You had selected the right answer before. What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [release 11.4.8](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1148-2018-11-27) of Gitlab it's not possible to expose project's Badges through a Personnal Access Token anymore. Because of the change "
Restrict Personal Access Tokens to API scope on web requests."

The commit that removed this "workaround" was [published as a security fix](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/fe5f75930e781ef854b458fafa307ebb90a8ed2e#6074c15e5681f6918e4dfed480f327e19098640c)

An [ongoing issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/54633) is currently being discussed to find another solution. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

That was followed by [issue 13324](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13324)

It includes:

> FYI, I have a workaround for this using the GitLab API.
> It **assumes you have created a token in GitLab for a user** (Note: That "user" needn't necessarily be Human - my use case is to display a badge on a dashboard hosted on a different VM).

```
<img src="https://<gitlab-uri>/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/build.svg?private_token=<token>
```

---

Update Dec. 2018: This is no loger possible through a token (see [Paul B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442487/paul-b)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53760663/6309)).

This is because of "[Improper Enforcement of Token Scope](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/28/security-release-gitlab-11-dot-5-dot-1-released/#improper-enforcement-of-token-scope)":

> The GitLab web interface was vulnerable to an authorization issue that allowed access to the web-UI as a user using their Personal Access Token (PAT) of any scope.
> The issue is now mitigated in the latest release and is assigned [CVE-2018-19569](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-19569).

But...:

> Updated: 2018-11-28: We have received reports that this change has impacted how repo files and job artifacts are downloaded for some users.
> For instructions on how to do so through the API, please see [our support issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/54572#note_120859334).

And you also have a [current workaround](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/55224#note_124280829) which repeats the API access:

It is possible to add the project avatar to the project repository with a particular filename (logo) and then this file will be used for the avatar. There is an example here:

https://gitlab.com/issue-reproduce/project-avatar-repo

> You'll be able to retrieve the files through the Repository Files API:
>
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/issue-reproduce%2Fproject-avatar-repo/repository/files/logo.png?ref=master
> ```

Comment: can it be a token without permissions for any project ?

Comment: @BigDong if the user whose token you using has access to all project (like an admin account), then yes: any project. You have some way to limit its scope: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#limiting-scopes-of-a-personal-access-token (and it is still improving: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41165)

Comment: The token for admin account will give read access to anonymous people to all our gitlab. Is that what you are recommending?

Comment: @BigDong no, I would recommend setting up a dedicated account per group, for restricting access to the projects that need that kind of access/usage. Again, this is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your workaround involves to open the project publicly so it should not be advised as it is. Could you please confirm that currently there is no way around other than making the project public? (token or general perms)

Comment: @BigDong no other workaround that I know of. And yes, that token would not give access just to the project build status. That is why https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41165 is so important.

Comment: I have upvoted your issues so we all get more visibility on it. Thanks